# Ag-grid angular 2 tree structure not displaying

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am getting below error after update ag-grid to latest version 4.2.6.

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null
    at e.recursivelyFilter (localhost:3000/node_modules/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.min.js:477:792)
    at e.execute (localhost:3000/node_modules/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.min.js:477:693)
    at e.doFilter (localhost:3000/node_modules/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.min.js:501:5814)
    at e.refreshModel (localhost:3000/node_modules/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.min.js:501:2078)
    at localhost:3000/node_modules/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.min.js:26:1476
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at e.dispatchEvent (localhost:3000/node_modules/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.min.js:26:1456)
    at e.setColumnDefs (localhost:3000/node_modules/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.min.js:80:21082)
    at e.init (localhost:3000/node_modules/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.min.js:80:6383)
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.min.js:38:3022"
```

Up to ag-grid 4.2.5 it was working fine. Anyone know the reason?

Comment: It looks like you're giving the grid an object, which doesn't have a value assigned to it. Can you show some template code and tell us how you fill the array for the grid?

Comment: <div class="relationGrid">
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 400px;" id="accountMappingTree" class="ag-file-browser"></div>
    </div>